# PayPal IPN Sandbox Payments - Pay On Delivery or Bank Payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to test PayPal payments that are authorised at a later date, examples being Pay on Delivery or a Bank Transfer.

I have created a new sandbox account with no credit/debit cards and £0 in the PayPal balance but when I come to make a payment I have to add a card.

I have set up a bank account and agreed the mandate so I must have something set up wrong somewhere because these type of payments happen in LIVE and we have an issue with the IPN message that comes X number of days later once the payment has cleared so I am trying to reproduce this to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the IPN Tester? (here after you log into your Sandbox account) https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/ .

All sorts of conditions that you can test your 'listener' process against there.